# Problem with DialogFragment creation and invocation

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm creating a simple `DialogFragment` with two buttons, which is supposed only to show a `Toast` when you select any of the two options. This dialog is displayed when you press one certain button on a activity.
For some reason, the code doesn't show any kind of error but when i click the button, the app crashes.
How do I resolve this?

I was first trying to do a custom XML file and java file for the `Dialog`, but i couldn't make that work either. `Google's documentation` and other tutorials didn't help either

public class Config extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button btncanc;
Button btnreestab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_config);
    btncanc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncnacelset);
    btnreestab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnrest);

    btncanc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Operación cancelada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            Config.this.finish();
        }
    });
    btnreestab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

            builder.setMessage("Hola");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hola",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancela", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"adios",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: can you please add your crash log?

Comment: sure, it says: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prueba, PID: 24362
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your style from your context. Make your alert dialog initialization with.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(Config.this)
```

in other way you can define a custom style in style.xml such as

```
<style name="myDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    ...
</style
```

and initialize alert dialog with

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), R.style.myDialog);
```

The reason for this crash is the `AppCompatActivity` has the Theme.AppCompat so you should use this theme. 
checkout that crash.

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what do you mean. Do I need to use an xml file anyways? Or only change the compatibility in the java file?

Comment: use like first.

Comment: still can't understand what you're trying to say, sorry

Comment: you can try to find where you are initializing your alert dialog in that you can `AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Config.this)`